# Tooltip: how do I retrieve the position of the point when the mouse hover it?

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to accomplish this: I have a data that is structured as following

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
0.1,0.2,0.3
```

I display #1 on y and #2 on x; and I would like to display #3 on the tooltip (#3 is saved in an array).

The tooltip can access to this.x and this.y, so the mouse knows on which point is, and is able to display the correct x and y values, so how can I get this value, so I can pass it as index of my array, and append it in the tooltip?

To be precise, I don't need the value of x and y of the point, but in which position of the series it is (example: series has 10 values, I hover on the second point, I should get 1, if I hover on the 10th point I should get 9 and so on).

Comment: can you provide a sample on jsfiddle or other demo tools?

Comment: I did a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/newbiez/2k48L/1/

Comment: Can you just edit your question to correspond to your fiddle? What do you want to display (in your sample)?

Comment: Besides the data that is different (used a fiddle that I was using for testing some time ago), the scope is the same: in the tooltip I want to display some values that are not in the x or y axis. I am just trying to figure out how do you find out the position of a point, when you use a tooltip, so I can retrieve the related value saved in a different array (check the code in the function inside the tooltip: I tried indexOf and it didn't work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your index with the following:

```
pointlocation = this.series.yData.indexOf(this.y);
```

Then your formatter will be:

```
formatter: function() {
    pointlocation = this.series.yData.indexOf(this.y);
    content=this.y + '<br/>' + letters[pointlocation] +'<br/>'; 
    return content;
}
```

See fiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/nrobert/2k48L/3/

Comment: Brilliant! So this is how do you refer to the point: you call the series that is on the x by name, trough the indexOf() function. I was using the wrong approach. Thanks!

Comment: I think your approach is better: we should use the data from the series instead of the var storing the data mapped initially.. I'm trying to improve it using this.series for the indexOf

Comment: I updated it to use this.series: when browsing the items, I saw that the easiest array is yData, where you can find indexOf this.y

Comment: Looks good, thanks Nicolas! I will try to hook up the real data and see how does it look like